# Object.entries and Object.values skip last item when used with 'import'

Tags: javascript, arrays, import, javascript-objects

I've run into a rather strange bug, I feel like my understanding of the expected behaviour of `Object.values` and `Object.entries` might be incomplete. I have an object containing five strings that I import from a file. When logging, I can see the object is imported correctly, all five strings are there. When I use `Object.values` or `Object.entries`, the resulting arrays only contain four elements, the last one being skipped. When used with destructuring, though, everything works as expected, all five elements are returned. Can you have a look at the code below and let me know what I might be missing? Are you able to reproduce this on your end?

```
// reducers.js
const Auth = 'Auth';
const ErrorManager = 'ErrorManager';
const Loading = 'Loading';
const Posts = 'Posts';
const UserData = 'UserData';

export { Auth, ErrorManager, Loading, Posts, UserData };

// another file
import * as reducers from './reducers';

console.log('This is the object:')
console.log(JSON.stringify(reducers));

console.log("This array is incomplete:");
console.log(JSON.stringify(Object.values(reducers)));
console.log("This array is complete:");
console.log(JSON.stringify(Object.values({ ...reducers })));
```

The log output is as follows:

```
This is the object:
{"Auth":"Auth","ErrorManager":"ErrorManager","Loading":"Loading","Posts":"Posts","UserData":"UserData"}

This array is incomplete:
["Auth","ErrorManager","Loading","Posts"]

This array is complete:
["Auth","ErrorManager","Loading","Posts","UserData"]
```

If I don't use import, everything works as expected, see below:

```
const Auth = 'Auth';
const ErrorManager = 'ErrorManager';
const Loading = 'Loading';
const Posts = 'Posts';
const UserData = 'UserData';

const reducers = { Auth, ErrorManager, Loading, Posts, UserData };

console.log('This is the object:')
console.log(JSON.stringify(reducers));

console.log("This array is complete:");
console.log(JSON.stringify(Object.values(reducers)));
```

Log output:

```
This is the object:
{"Auth":"Auth","ErrorManager":"ErrorManager","Loading":"Loading","Posts":"Posts","UserData":"UserData"}

This array is complete:
["Auth","ErrorManager","Loading","Posts","UserData"]
```

Comment: Does it always skip last item? Did you try to add some more items and observe the behaviour?

Comment: @31piy yes, the same happens whether I use fewer or more items. With a single item, I get an empty array.

Comment: Are you using a transpiler like babel?maybe issue with that?

Comment: @ShyamBabu The app was created with `react-native init` and it generated a configuration which uses babel-preset-react-native. I'm not very familiar with babel, do you think this might be the issue?

Comment: @user2634633 could be. Could you try a for in loop and see if the problem persists?

Comment: @ShyamBabu Just tried with `for (let x in reducers) {...` and everything works - all five results are logged

Comment: In node(>8.9.4) experimental mode this seems to be working as you expected. You can test it by naming the files with .mjs and running with --experimental-modules flag. Its probably issue with some config, you should raise it at babel or at react-native repo for better help.

Comment: I've imported the files as you did and executed the above mentioned code on node js application and it is working fine.